# Who OR which dilemma

Tags: pronouns

Having no amount of choices and hence availing of "what" we can ask:

> 1) What flamethrower do you want?

Having some listed amount we will use "which":

> 2) Which one of these flamethrowers do you want?

If we have no listed quantity for the alive figure:

> 3) Who do you want to help to?

Having that it will be "which" or still "who":

> 4) Who of them will be sent a present by her to?
>
> 5) Which of them will be sent a present by her to?

Comment: Only your first two sentences are grammatical.

Answer (score 0):

As the first two are correct, I will fix your last three.

> Who do you want to help to? **Incorrect**
>
> Who do you want to help? **Correct**

---

> Who of them will be sent a present by her to? **Incorrect**
>
> Who (among them) will receive a present from her? **Correct**

- "among them" is optional, so you can omit it.

---

> Which of them will be sent a present by her to? **Incorrect**
>
> Which one of them will receive a present from her? **Correct**

---

You can also restructure the last two sentences like this:

> Whom will she send a present to? **Correct**

Or

> To whom will she send a present? **Correct**

---

A side note, "alive figure" is a strange thing to refer to humans/people by. Say something like human/person instead.

Comment: Example 2 : they are not sending her the present, she is choosing who, amongst them, will receive the present.

Comment: 1) But isn't "help" like "tell", "give", "call" like:
tell TO somebody, give TO somebody, call TO somebody and help TO somebody. Otherwise it will be: I will tell you(I am addressing to a story, book, novel). Like, hey, book, I have a friend who wants to now you, and I know your plot and I will tell you (to him). Saying "I tell you"(addressing to a person) sounds stupid.
2) "Who of them will receive a present from her" is already incorrect, too because of "of them"?
3) If we can say "He is sent for" why can't we say "he is sent a doctor for" and then "he was sent a present to"?

Comment: But I mean this:
1) What apple do you want? 2) I have two pies. Which pie(or which one) do you want?
3) What person do you know? 4) I have 3 friends. Who OR which person do you know?
I mean we can use "what" and "which" for things depending on the fact if we have some limited amount. But if we have some limited amount for people we still use "which" or it will be only "who" because "which" is only for things?

Comment: 1-) "Help", "Tell", "Give", and "Call" aren't followed by the preposition "To" and, indeed, they sound a bit strange when they are in the present simple tense. So, I have put them in different tenses to give you the feeling of their normal nature without the "To". We say: "I **have told** him many times **to call** her by her name." "I **will help** you getting over this dilemma, and I **am giving** you some examples." This one in the present simple: "We **tell** them what they want to hear." Another thing, you don't say: "I tell you." but "I **am telling** you."

Comment: 2-) Yes, it is incorrect but not because of **them** but because of its current structure which happened to include **them**. 3-) Actually, ending sentences with prepositions is something a lot of natives don't approve. Also, when you say: "He is sent a doctor for." It would be understood as there was someone who sent him a doctor which is weird. Say instead: "He was sent to see a doctor." Or better: "He went to see a doctor." I'm not very sure of the intended meaning, so clarifying that would help me in my explanation.

Comment: 1-) You can say either "Whay do you want?" or "Which apple do you want?" in case you have many of them. 2-) "Which pie do you want?" 3-) Say "Whom do you know?" **Which** and **what** are not preferred to use when referring to people. 4-) I suggest you say: "Among these three, whom do you know?" **Whom** not **who** as the answer would be an object, not a subject. - Yes, but be careful to not confuse **who** with **whom**. You say: "Who is my friend?" (The answer would be a subject.) "Whom do you like?" (The answer is an object.)